# Load Vue Components dynamically when accordion is expanded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way I can load a Vue component when a user clicks on the header of Buefy collapse.

Comment: Async Components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

Answer (score 0):

You can use **v-show** directive on the component to toggle the display property of the component. For example -

```
<your-component v-show="isActive"></your-component>
```

Now, if isActive is true, then **your-component** will be shown. You can pragmatically make isActive false to hide the component, like clicking outside of the component may hide the component and clicking on the header make the component visible. All you need to do toggle the value of isActive property.